# HP UFT - how to get date range from two input dates

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

I am trying to get the date range from two input dates eg: "01.10.2016" and "05.10.2016" (its a date format in SAP)

I thinking date format is wrong, if it is wrong could anyone help me to how to convert this format as acceptable.

Also i'm trying to get all the date between two dates including limits and using it for automation. if any one know how to get all the dates help me in this.

Comment: `Dim newdate: newdate = Replace(inputdate, ".", "/")` you can then convert it to a proper date using `CDate()`.

Comment: Thanks lankymart. Did you know how to get all dates between two dates range?

Comment: Depends what you want to do `DateDiff()` allows you to compare two dates and return an "interval" between them which can be in days, months, years etc. However if you want to a return a list of dates between two dates then you need to use a `Do` loop and `DateAdd()` to increment a start date by 1 day and continually check in the loop to see if you reach the end date, while outputting the dates in between. Ideally though you need to show us that you have at least attempted something by providing a [mcve]. If this is unclear please read [ask] before posting.

Comment: `s = "01.10.2016": l = SetLocale(1031): d = CDate(s): SetLocale l` to convert the string with date in input format to date type. 1031 is LocaleID for Germany.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DD.MM.YYYY` is the date format used in Germany, where SAP have their headquarters. If you're using the right locale you should be able to convert the date string to a date directly via [`CDate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dt118h2%28v=vs.84%29.aspx).

```
s = "01.10.2016"
d = CDate(s)
```

If that doesn't work for you (because your regional settings differ) you can for instance split the string at dots and build a date from the fragments via [`DateSerial`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1we4t8hy%28v=vs.84%29.aspx):

```
s = "01.10.2016"
a = Split(s, ".")
d = DateSerial(a(2), a(1), a(0))
```

Once you converted the strings to date values you can calculate the difference between the two dates by subtracting one from the other

```
delta = d2 - d1
```

or by using the [`DateDiff`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhtyw595%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) function:

```
delta = DateDiff("d", d1, d2)
```

The individual dates `d1` through `d2` can be calculated for instance like this:

```
For i=0 To DateDiff("d", d1, d2)
  WScript.Echo d1+i
Next
```

Comment: Thanks Ansgar. It is really helpful for me to understand the datediff and DateSerial.

Comment: DateSerial is a good approach. It makes the script , machine locale agnostic.